# How to share common code between microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

I have 3 microservices which have some common code like constants, exceptions ,DTO etc. I want them to be part of common library instead of copy pasting in every service (to avoid DRY). How to achieve this in spring boot ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right to want to stop copy-pasting.
This problem can be solved with shared dependencies (like for a classic project).

You must use the semantic version for the version change (only the major version can integrate breaks).

Next, you need to deal with backwards compatibility.

EDIT :

You could use maven or probably gradle. At home, we made an immutable package and a small homemade package manager (to avoid cumbersome maven package publication).
you also have github submodules (but be careful and read the doc https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)

Comment: Right ! I just started learning microservices. Do you have any sources on how to implement this in spring boot?

Comment: You have several solutions (not spring specific).
You could use maven or probably gradle.
At home, we made an immutable package and a small homemade package manager (to avoid cumbersome maven package publication)